# Inner Joining big tables in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to perform an inner join between two big tables where each table consists of almost 30 million records. When I try running a simple INNER JOIN between these two tables I get an error as below asking me to use JOIN EACH syntax but I didn't find any proper documentation on google references for JOIN EACH. Can somebody share thoughts about this? Here is my error as below.

```
Error: Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins  Did you see that one? or you need more than what this one gives?

Comment: looks good. I have changed my code and its working fine.

Comment: Added an answer, with a bit more background info :) feel free to ask for clarification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your question, seems like all you need is to read up a bit on the [doc available](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins).

Now, having read Jordan Tigani's book, I can tell you that when you join, the system actually sends the smaller table in every shard that handles your query. Since none of your table is under 8 Mb, what happens is that it cannot simply send your table (as it's simply too big).

The way "JOIN EACH" works is that it tells the system "hash the joining criteria on both tables, and send a subset of each table to a specific shard". Hashing means that whatever you use as a criteria for the inner join will actually end up in the same shard. It has impacts on performance, but it's the only thing that can make a JOIN where both tables are bigger than 8 mb go through.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ' after and before the table and then .column name.  Where to put the ' was causing me confusion as well.

Example:

'employee_data.employees`.department_id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).